# How to extract multiple tags using xmllint

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xmllint

I'm trying to fetch data using soap apis. I'm using curl command with below soap body and using xmllint with --xpath option (**xmllint --xpath "//return/id/text()" -**) to fetch all id values from all return tags. But im getting the values in same line (like 13576454554535536).
But what i'm expexting is:

```
1357645
45545
35536
```

```
   <S:Body>
      <ns2:getSomeResp xmlns:ns2="http://wd.emaple.com/de">
         <return>
            <id>1357645</id>
         </return>
         <return>
            <id>45545</id>
         </return>
         <return>
            <id>35536</id>
         </return>
      </ns2:getSomeResp>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Could someone please help?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't reproduce with version `xmllint: using libxml version 20914`

```
xmllint --xpath "//return/id/text()" tmp.xml
1357645
45545
35536
```

Alternatively, it can be done as follows

```
printf '%s\n' "cat //return/id/text()" "bye" | xmllint --shell <(cat tmp.xml)
```

Result

```
/ > cat //return/id/text()
 -------
1357645
 -------
45545
 -------
35536
/ > bye
```

**Note**: `xmllint` can not read its shell commands and xml input from stdin at the same time. It's one or the other.
This will fail to read the xpath :
`echo "cat //return/id/text()" | xmllint --shell - < tmp.xml`
But can be done with [<(cmd) process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution) since it creates a FIFO or uses a file descriptor thus behaving like a file.
`echo "cat //return/id/text()" | xmllint --shell <(cat tmp.xml)`